# Pattern in Blender geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]like on picture below. How to do this kind of pattern. It is made by star and next row is number of star points divided by 2.
[image]

Comment: *"...next row is number of star points divided by 2"* ...I honestly can't really see that here. According to which mathematical principle should this be built? Is it only about the edges, or should this be a mesh with faces? Or should these be curves? Please tell us more, show what you've tried so far so we don't have to figure out the whole solution for you. Thank you!

Comment: Hi thank You for comment. It should be mesh with faces. I will do more precise image please wait...